# GAE app "Push-to-deploy" failed for wordpress git

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, jenkins, bitbucket

I'm currently trying to set up a GAE push-to-deploy from my bitbucket wordpress repo.
Seems like all the needed steps for setting up jenkins on GCE were done, but build failed with `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.config'`

I think shell command: `gcloud --project=projectjp01 preview app deploy .` added to the build step caused problem. (looks like jenkins user cannot access root folder or log folder )

Could someone help me out successfully accomplishing this push-to-depoly process for GAE?
Any helps will be appreciated.

FYI, below are the console message for the build process:

> Started by user User Name Building in workspace
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/firstjenkins/workspace
>
> > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> >     /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://source.developers.google.com/p/projectjp01 # timeout=10
> >     Fetching upstream changes from
> >     source.developers.google.com/p/projectname
> >     /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git --version # timeout=10 using .gitcredentials to set credentials
> >     /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git config --local credential.helper store --file=/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/temp/git2753293187622835876.credentials
> >
> > ## timeout=10
> >
> > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git fetch --tags --progress 
> >     +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> >     /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
> >     /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
> >     /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} > # timeout=10 Checking out
> >     Revision 2297db6db06f19198dd3097e8db6b72687e8d433
> >     (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> >     /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> >     /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git checkout -f 2297db6db06f19198dd3097e8db6b72687e8d433
> >     /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git rev-list 2297db6db06f19198dd3097e8db6b72687e8d433 # timeout=10 [workspace] $
> >     /bin/sh -xe
> >     /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/temp/hudson1649832068994489242.sh
> >     + gcloud --project=projectname preview app deploy . Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> >     "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py",
> >     line 177, in 
> >         _cli = CreateCLI()   File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py",
> >     line 175, in CreateCLI
> >         return loader.Generate()   File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py",
> >     line 236, in Generate
> >         return self.__LoadCLIFromGroups()   File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py",
> >     line 280, in __LoadCLIFromGroups
> >         cli = self.__MakeCLI(top_group)   File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py",
> >     line 442, in __MakeCLI
> >         log.AddFileLogging(self.__logs_dir)   File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py",
> >     line 532, in AddFileLogging
> >         _log_manager.AddLogsDir(logs_dir=logs_dir)   File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py",
> >     line 316, in AddLogsDir
> >         log_file = self._SetupLogsDir(logs_dir)   File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py",
> >     line 393, in _SetupLogsDir
> >         os.makedirs(day_dir_path)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
> >         makedirs(head, mode)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
> >         makedirs(head, mode)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
> >         makedirs(head, mode)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
> >         mkdir(name, mode) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.config' Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
> >     Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself. All the problem comes from permission setting.

gcloud should be run as sudo but the tomcat (jenkins) configured to disable the sudo by default.
So I ssh to the GCE server where jenkins are running, open(create) file with:

```
sudo vi /etc/sudoers.d/tomcat
```

and then put this line:

```
tomcat ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

that's it. I can build & deploy without problem now.